# How to nest joins of subqueries in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I am trying to implement an automatic query generator, and my approach for one kind of queries is to have nested joins in such way
Select * From (( Q1 join Q2 on Q1.x = Q2.x) As T1 Join Q3 on T1.x=Q3) As T2) Join Q4 on T2.x = Q4.x ) As T3 ... and so on

I tried to implement it in such way but the syntax seem to be wrong

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        (
          Select
            *
          From
            Customers
        ) AS q11
        INNER JOIN (
          Select
            *
          From
            Customers
        ) AS q12 ON q11.customerID = q12.customerID
    )
  ) q1
  JOIN (
    Select
      *
    from
      Customers
  ) q2 ON q1.q11.CustomerID = q2.CustomerID
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra () on your first sub select.

Comment: What's with all those brackets?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS "syntax seem to be wrong" is useless. Give your code & error message & google the error message & read answers. Read the manual & a textbook on how to use SQL.

Comment: Why is there code in your first paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more compact version would be:

```
;WITH Data AS(Select * From Customers)

SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    Data D1
    INNER JOIN Data D2 ON D2.ID=D1.ID
    INNER JOIN Data D3 ON D3.ID=D2.ID
    INNER JOIN Data D4 ON D4.ID=D3.ID
    INNER JOIN Data D5 ON D5.ID=D4.ID
    INNER JOIN Data D6 ON D6.ID=D5.ID
    INNER JOIN Data D7 ON D7.ID=D6.ID
```

And even more compact:

```
SELECT * FROM D D1
JOIN D D2 ON D2.ID=D1.ID
JOIN D D3 ON D3.ID=D2.ID
JOIN D D4 ON D4.ID=D3.ID
JOIN D D5 ON D5.ID=D4.ID
JOIN D D6 ON D6.ID=D5.ID
JOIN D D7 ON D7.ID=D6.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that worked. Only problem now is if I have for example Select ID it tells me Reference 'ID' is ambiguous, could be: D1.ID, D2.Id , any ideas how to solve this? I can't always type D1.ID , as I could also need a variable from second or 3rd Join. ID here is an alias not a real column name

Comment: Not sure I am following.. Do you want each field to be aliased as a concatenation of join name + field name --> D1_ID | D1_Name | D2_ID | D2_Name? Do you want the data stacked vertical (as in a UNION) or horizontal?

Comment: Never mind. I understood from the example that the joins have to use column names from only the tables they are between, for example I could not use On D2.ID = D3.ID between D3 and D4 (needed for the case where every sub-query selects different columns). It turns out that this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Select statements & subqueries do not return columns with dots.

So q1.q11.CustomerID makes no sense.

An SQL JOIN calculates a cross join. That value first has a column per left table column, with the names of the left table columns; then that value has a column per right table column, with the names of the right table columns. The columns are *identified* by dotted column names aka column references, but their names have no dots. A `SELECT *` returns all those columns--so it returns duplicate names when input tables share names. But not dots in names.

Comment: In my Queries if I wrote in the main query select X for example it would be refused. I have to specify Q0.X or Q1.X, so I thought it keeps piling on the names of tables.

Comment: Don't "think" (or--what I expect you really meant--guess or hope), read the manual. PS "it would be refused" is useless. Give code & error messages in your question. PS Why did you write that comment? Do you understand that my answer says that what you thought was wrong? PS If an answer best answers your question then you can click on the check mark icon to show that & distribute reputation points. Google 'stackexchange accept answer'. When you have enough reputation you can upvote & downvote.

Answer (score 0):

A query in the from clause is suitable in creating tables.

select * from ( select * from (  select * from ( select * from q1,q2 where q1.x=q2.x ) t1 , q3 where t1.x=q3.x ) t2 ,  q4 where t2.x=q4.x ) t3 ,  q5 where t3.x=q5.x

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.